# Apply colours to a line graph using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have produced a line graph using ggplot. The data contains two groups with 9 samples each that were followed up over 11 time points (x-values). Now, I have tried to give each sample line of one group an individual colour, while giving only a single colour to the samples of the other group  (here: black).
Here is the important part of my script.

```
data <- read.csv2("140929 example.csv",check.names = FALSE)
library(reshape2)
data.m <- melt(data)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.m, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = Group,colour = Group))+
geom_line()+
theme_bw()
```

This turns out a graph with individual colours for all lines.

How can I improve? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Posting output of "head(data)" and "str(data)" here will help others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hard to tell without data or a picture of your current plot.  But you can try assigning a new variable to your `data.m` to control color.  I.E. set a new variable up as a sequence then for the solid color group set it up to be the same throughout that group.

```
data.m$mycolor <- 1:nrow(data.m)
data.m[data.m$group == somegroup,]$mycolor <- 0
```

Then in your aesthetic use `colour = mycolor`